# Delay displaying a fixed bar, but hide it instantly

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following code which delays showing a fixed bar after a certain point.

The code hides the fixed bar if you scroll up to the top, but automatically shows the bar after 2 seconds, even though the scroll point is below 70, so it should be hidden all together.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 70) {
            $('#mini-header').delay(2000).show(0);
        } else if($(window).scrollTop() < 70) {
            $('#mini-header').hide();
        }
    });
```

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKqMN/) shows the behaivor.

Comment: How can I make the fixed bar display after 2000ms, after it passed the 70 point, but have it automatically removed when you're up. Currently, it hides once its up but its being shown after 2000ms - even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `else if` to a simple `else` and hide the div by `display: none` - 
[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fKqMN/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 70) {
                $('#mini-header').delay(2000).show();
            } else {
                $('#mini-header').css("display", "none");
            }
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fKqMN/23/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 70 ) {
                $('#mini-header').stop().animate({ opacity:1 }, 2000, function() {
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                });
            } else {
                $('#mini-header').stop().animate({ opacity:0 }).css("display", "none");
            }
    });
});
```

The `animate()` acts like a `delay()` but the difference - you can `stop()` it.

Answer (score 0):

removing the 0 from show() seems to do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/Ds4Ls/

Comment: Yes, but that will disable the delay to show the bar after 2000.